# Do the SQL commands typed in psql belong to SQL (SQL dialect of Postgresql) or PL/PgSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql, psql

Do  the SQL commands typed in psql belong to

- SQL (SQL dialect of Postgresql) or
- PL/PgSQL?

In other words,should I  use SQL (SQL dialect of Postgresql) or PL/PgSQL in  psql?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are not plpgsql unless you declare a block of plpgsql (or any other pl language). Otherwise commands are assumed to be SQL syntax if not psql slash commands like \set or \dt.

Comment: Thanks!  How would you  declare a block of plpgsql (or any other pl language) in psql?

Comment: Anonymous blocks are started with the [DO](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/sql-do.html) command.

Comment: Thanks. Do SQL standard and any other major RDBMS such as MySQL and SQL Server have equivalent command to DO in PostgreSQL?

Comment: I know Oracle has their PL/SQL equivalent, anonymous PL/SQL blocks are started with a `DECLARE` statement. It's the same language used to write functions and stored procedures.

I can't speak to MySQL or MS SQL Server.